# ForkJoinPool task priorities

Tags: java

Using `ForkJoinPool`, suppose I submit main `ForkJoinTask`, that eventually invokes 20 other sub-tasks. Right after that I submit another similar main task.

What I would like to achieve, is that main tasks would be processed in first-in first-out order. Now the problem is, that sub-tasks on second task may already start executing before first one is ready: thus causing some sub-tasks from first main task to wait.

So, if I'm able to calculate one main task per second and make 10 submissions, I would like to get results on seconds: 1, 2, 3, .., not 10 results together at the end.

If this is not possible using `ForkJoinPool`, which are other options to achieve desired result?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to compute two (main) tasks in parallel, you should not run them concurrently. Is weird to tell the `ForkJoinPool`: 'Here is my task B, please execute it, but not yet - wait until task A has completed!'

In other words: Instead of tweaking the pool or your task implementation, you should rather await the computation of the first task before submitting the second task.

For example:

```
ForkJoinTask taskA = ...;
ForkJoinTask taskB = ...;

taskA.invoke(); // awaits completion
taskB.invoke();
```

Alternatively you can use on of the `invoke(...)` methods on class `ForkJoinPool`.

Comment: Consider this case: main task may consist on 3 subtasks, which take 0.5, 0.5 and 1 seconds to run. And after 1 second we get final result.
Though after 0.5 seconds we have also 2 slots free and could use them. Using this solution we'll be idling, not processing further tasks.

Comment: @iljau I've got the point. That's indeed a problem then. I'm currently thinking about if a `Phaser` could be used for some kind of synchronization, but I don't have any idea yet how to do that.

Comment: That question really make sense. Java also has PriorityBlockinqQueue but can not be used with ForkJoinPool. @iljau how did you solved your problem? I have same problem.